# How to extend class in database first ASP MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In a code first database - the class can be made abstract, have annotations and extended. Example:

```
public abstract class Person
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FirstMidName { get; set; }

    public string FullName
    {
        get
        {
            return LastName + ", " + FirstMidName;
        }
    }
```

a child class can inherit the abstract class and extend it further. Example:

```
public class Instructor : Person
{
    public DateTime HireDate { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Course> Courses { get; set; }
    public virtual OfficeAssignment OfficeAssignment { get; set; }
}
```

the child class is referenced in the code no differently tan the abstract class

In a database first you cannot modify the class. Is it possible to accomplish the above with a Database First project. Re there examples or links on how to?

Comment: Are the database-first classes marked as `partial`?  If they are, you can extend them pretty easily I would think.  If they aren't, as long as they're not marked as `sealed` you should be able to inherit from the base class.  EF is not my strong suit yet, so I may be missing some of the nuances of the EF approach.

Answer (score 0):

In database first, every class created by EF is partial(for example "public partial class Country"). So the best approach is creating another class with the same name and with partial keyword, and add what ever you want in second class!. The good point is if you change your database and recreate your classes by EF, the second class remains unchanged and so your extensions are always there.